# AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def spider(max_page):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_page:
        url = 'https://thenewboston.com/forum/recent_activity.php?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'title text-semibold'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
            page += 1
spider(1)


output---------------------------------
C:\Users\Edwardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/Edwardo/PycharmProjects/pythonJourney/spider.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Edwardo/PycharmProjects/pythonJourney/spider.py", line 14, in <module>
    spider(1)
  File "C:/Users/Edwardo/PycharmProjects/pythonJourney/spider.py", line 7, in spider
    source_code = requests.get(url)
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: after doing some searching for this problem, it seems likely to pop up when you have either another script named `requests.py` sitting in your current directory or in your Python path.

Comment: What's the output of `dir(requests)`?

Comment: ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Answer (score 6):

You have another file with this name "requests". You need change it and try again.

Also, you can try to use *pip* for reinstall *requests*:

```
pip install requests -U
```

Comment: No i don't have one, i cross check all the files in my dir

Comment: my previous  python programs  work very fine with requests.get but now all those program give me error AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @EdwardAlex, this problem has two variants: 1) you have another script with this name. 2) you have bad standart library request. Try find another script or use **pip install requests -U**

Comment: thanx bro,i uninstall and reinstall  requests so now its working

Comment: no still the same error

Comment: I am having the same issue. No other "requests" file on my system. If I uninstall requests and reinstall it, I can import requests one time at the Python3.7 prompt, but then it will error if I exit and try again. One thing I do notice is that a __pycache__ file is created.

Comment: @Calab Probably, u have another file with same name (like requests.py). Check out

Comment: You were right... it was "http.py" that got me.