# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.auth'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-requests, conda

Shortly, a script of mine, that had run just fine, stopped working, throwing a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.auth'

I don't remember having changed the Conda environment the script uses.

Everything worked fine one day and stopped the next. I don't know which parameter has changed.

I tried several paths to find a solution, but I was not successful. Among them were:

- setting up a new, clean the [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) environment, definitely installed requests
- clearing Visual Studio Code's cache
- several reboots

The strange part is this: When I run the following commands in an interactive session in the shell, it works and I receive a "Response [200]".

When I run it in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) or .py file in Visual Studio Code, I get above mentioned ModuleNotFoundError. The same goes for executing the file from the command line.

All the above tests were conducted in the same Conda environment which definitely has [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) installed.

Also: It does work in a virtual environment I have access to, to which my Visual Studio Code settings are synced. So maybe not Visual Studio Code, but something local to my machine?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

basic = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')

requests.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=basic)
```

**Some specifications:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: 3.12.2
- Requests: 2.31.0
- Conda: 24.1.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ultimately, the resolution to the issue was unexpectedly straightforward and stemmed from a fundamental user mistake.

**The issue** arose due to a sub-directory named "requests" within the project folder. Consequently, when attempting to import the library using `import requests`, the sub-directory was imported instead of the intended library.
Lacking the necessary modules, this resulted in the `MouleNotFoundError`.

**The solution** was equally straightforward: renaming the problematic folder instantly restored the functionality of the import process and, thus, the scripts.

**Regarding my tests,** upon reflection, it becomes evident that the import of requests.auth functioned properly in settings outside the impacted project directory, such as in a generic interactive session in the command line or on the remote virtual machine. However, the import failed when within the confines of the project directory, a scenario observed in the mentioned .py and .ipynb files.

**Nota bene:** never name something like an existing library

The following solution helped me track down my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522445/21402820

Comment: This is a link-only answer to another SO question. This should be a comment, or the question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. Before the link, I clearly stated what did cause the error and how I solved it.

Comment: Hope the new extended version of my answer satisfies the requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Python interpreter by shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose your correct Python interpreter.

If it doesn't work, try command `pip install requests`.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that I have tried that with the correct interpreter. I even set up a new environment.

I was under the impression that I should not mix conda and pip install in the same virtual environment. I can try that for sure - however my tests in the interactive session seem to show that requests is installed just fine. Also, this same script did work previously in the same environment.